# Align child views inside of RelativeLayout to match right border of parent

Tags: android, xml, layout, border, overlap

Basically, there is one RelativeLayout and two child views (TextViews). One of a child has a greater width than the other (it depends on their content cos child's width set to "wrap_content"). How to move smallest TV, that its right border matches right border of its container (RL)?
Situation
[image: Situation]

Desired alocation
[image: Desired alocation]

XML:

```
<RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:gravity="right"
        >
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/effect_text"
        android:textSize="100sp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textColor="@color/transparent_color"
        android:text="88:88"
        />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text"
            android:textSize="100sp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:shadowColor="@color/text_shadow"
            android:shadowDx="1"
            android:shadowDy="1"
            android:shadowRadius="10"
            android:text="12:34"/>
    </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: show your layout.xml file with question

Answer (score 1):

Did you write it in this manner?

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/effect_text"
    android:textSize="100sp"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textColor="#fbb"
    android:text="88:88"
    />
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/text"
    android:textSize="100sp"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textColor="#abb"
    android:shadowDx="1"
    android:shadowDy="1"
    android:shadowRadius="10"
    android:text="12:34"/>
```

Comment: Not working. And its amaze me. Using margin is working but this mean is not satisfied me.

Answer (score 0):

try this just make your second `textview` `android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/effect_text"` to your first `Textview`

like below Code

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"  >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/effect_text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:text="88:88"
        android:textColor="@color/transparent_color"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/effect_text"
        android:shadowColor="@color/text_shadow"
        android:shadowDx="1"
        android:shadowDy="1"
        android:shadowRadius="10"
        android:text="12:34"
        android:textStyle="bold" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/effect_text" makes left border of second TV match right border of first TV. Not working:(

Comment: try to add some **android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"** to your second textview @oleg_phorostyna

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="right">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/effect_text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="88:88"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/text"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textSize="100sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:shadowColor="@color/text_shadow"
        android:shadowDx="1"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:shadowDy="1"
        android:shadowRadius="10"
        android:text="12:34"
        android:textSize="100sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
</RelativeLayout>
```